# Laravel 5.3 Upload an image with Auth user::create

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I am trying to add an image to the user. To create the user I use 
system make:Auth but I don't know how can I get the file name because on 
`create(array $data)` I don't receive the file name.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'img' => 
    ]);
}
```

I can't put `'img' = $data['img']` because I need the file name.

How can i get the file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `getClientOriginalName` method because it's symfony [UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) instance try this :

`data['img']->getClientOriginalName();`